# geometry optimization problem

Tags: calculus

Good day! Is this problem require ratio ? I can't figure out how to deal with this. The problem is to find the radius of the right circular cylinder of largest volume that can be inscribed in a right circular cone with radius 6 inches and height 10 inches. Any help will be greatly appreciated thankx!

Comment: What are your  attempts while starting?

Comment: Slice it through the axis of the cone to get down to 2D and draw a picture.  You should find a relationship between the radius and height of the cylinder, constrained by the cone.

Comment: the answer is 4 right?

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDnMpSuqQv0